# Return Neo4J Combined Relationships When Searching Across Several Relationship Types

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I would like to query for various things and returned a combined set of relationships. In the example below, I want to return all people named Joe living on Main St. I want to return both the has_address and has_state relationships.

```
MATCH (p:Person), 
  (p)-[r:has_address]-(a:Address),
  (a)-[r1:has_state]-(s:State)
WHERE p.name =~ ".*Joe.*" AND a.street = ".*Main St.*"
RETURN r, r1;
```

But when I run this query in the Neo4J browser and look under the "Text" view, it seems to put r and r1 as columns in a table (something like this):

```
│r  │r1 │
╞═══╪═══|
│{} │{} │
```

rather than as desired with each relationship on a different row, like:

```
Joe Smith | has_address | 1 Main Street 
1 Main Street | has_state | NY
Joe Richards | has_address | 22 Main Street
```

I want to download this as a CSV file for filtering elsewhere. How do I re-write the query in Neo4J to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Cypher cheat sheet](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/), specifically the Relationship Functions.

That said, you have variables on all the nodes you need. You can output all the data you need on each row.

```
MATCH (p:Person), 
  (p)-[r:has_address]-(a:Address),
  (a)-[r1:has_state]-(s:State)
WHERE p.name =~ ".*Joe.*" AND a.street = ".*Main St.*"
RETURN p.name AS name, a.street AS address, s.name AS state
```

That should be enough.

What you seem to be asking for above is a way to union r and r1, but in such a way that they alternate in-order, one row being r and the next being its corresponding r1. This is a rather atypical kind of query, and as such there isn't a lot of support for easily making this kind of output.

If you don't mind rows being out of order, it's easy to do, but your start and end nodes for each relationship are no longer the same type of thing.

```
MATCH (p:Person), 
  (p)-[r:has_address]-(a:Address),
  (a)-[r1:has_state]-(s:State)
WHERE p.name =~ ".*Joe.*" AND a.street = ".*Main St.*"
WITH COLLECT(r) + COLLECT(r1) as rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
RETURN startNode(rel) AS start, type(rel) AS type, endNode(rel) as end
```